# On which stackexchange site should this be posted?

Tags: discussion

On which stackexchange site should [What are the steps to integrate a new mailman list?](https://serverfault.com/questions/515331/what-are-the-steps-to-integrate-a-new-mailman-list) have been asked?

Mailman runs on a server and I needed help configuring it.

Addemdum:

I posted this question, because, without turning into a spineless pretzel, I respect each of the stackexchange sites. and try to adapt to the culture of the site.. StackOverflow is different than this site, which is different than SuperUser and so on.

Comment: Why are you asking this? Do you have any indication on it being posted on the wrong site?

Comment: @pauska: I guess having it closed off topic here is an indication, though I suspect rather than OT it is NC as it's a very broad question.

Comment: @Iain it's not closed? Not even a single vote..

Comment: Oh, it's been reopened.

Comment: @pauska Sorry, I am just answering you, and as you noted it was closed and is now re-opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServerFault or unix.SE should be a perfect fit for this question. I have no idea why someone voted to close it.

Comment: My assumption would be because this is (or at least should be) covered in the mailman docs. But a pointer to the appropriate docs would certainly be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are not a Professional System Administrator (or similar). Questions about software that runs on a "server" (a pretty meaningless classification in the broad scheme of things) aren't automatically on-topic on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Please have a look through our [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq). Once done, take a look at [Super User](http://superuser.com) and [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com), as these sites are more appropriate for user questions.

Any question that can be simply answered by "Read the Friendly Manual" and pointing to a semi-obvious spot in the documentation is off-topic for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: I am a sysadmin along with being a DBA and developer. Give this was not a programming or programming tools like vim problem, I thought ServerFault was the right place. I could have gone on the mailman list, but I have found stackexchange wants and expects detailed questions and provides very good answers.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Your profile claims you are a Programmer, you only identify as a "sysadmin" when it suits you. It sounds more like you are a programmer tasks with administrative duties as your organization lacks a proper systems administrator. Stack Exchange does want good/detailed questions, but generally ones where the answer isn't "Have you turned it off and back on again?". I'm sorry if that's picky, but it's a constant battle to prevent [SF] from becoming help desk for the Internet.

Comment: @ChrisS - **Should we do background checks on posters and read their profiles**?

Comment: @DeerHunter I only read people's profiles if their question "feels" off-topic and don't want to come across as a grumpy sysadmin. 99% of the time when I see a question like "I haven't RTFM, but how do I $common_task with $popular_software" it's from a Programmer who either can't be bothered to read documentation or who knew enough about IT to become to unofficial SysAdmin but doesn't actually know how to do the job. I'm all for helping newbies, but there's a distinctly different mindset between these camps and "they" are only coming here to get free tech support. Better/Worse??

Comment: In my mind's vision: a new movie to the tune of Alien vs. Predator, but titled "Programmers vs. SysAdmins". Directed by: Simon Travaglia. Think it is better to direct newbies to Limoncelli (the book, not the man - he's on SE staff now AFAIR) to at least show them the Tao...